# Translation file magento 2 i18n

Tags: tax, localisation, vat, i18n

I'm trying to change **"Excl. Tax:" to "Excl. Vat:"** and have created a CSV file called **en_GB.csv** which contains the line - **"Tax:", "Vat:"**.

I've saved and uploaded this to **app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/i18n/en_GB.csv**.
The translation hasn't worked as my store still shows **"Excl. Tax".**
I've deployed static files and run the upgrade command too.
Not too sure what to try next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the manual translation doesn't work, you can try [Magento generation of translation dictionary](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-dict) by collecting **translatable phrases** in Magento 2.3.x.

Since you are configuring a Magento store in **`en_GB`** language. You can collect translatable phrases through this command:

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases --output "app/i18n/Magento/en_GB.csv" --magento
```

After running the above command, you can check and open the file with the collected translatable phrases from this path **app/i18n/Magento/en_GB.csv**
From there you can find and replace every **"Excl. Tax"** translatable phrase.
After you finish changing those words, you should run below command:

```
php bin/magento i18n:pack app/i18n/Magento/en_GB.csv -d en_GB
```

Flush cache. And your changes will reflect in the frontend.

Comment: @Eddie did you try this one?

Comment: Yes I've tried this command but get the following error 'Cannot open file for write dictionary: "app/i18n/Magento/en_GB.csv"' I'm still looking in to it as with other methods. I finding there is lots of conflicting information online with how this should be done.

Comment: Please ignore the comment above. I thought the command created the en_GB.csv file. When I created the empty file with that path you suggested and run the command it returned the translatable phrase. Using find and replace I changed tax to vat and it worked

Answer (score 1):

You need to use full phrase  (this one was without ":") :

```
"Excl. Tax","Excl. Vat"
```

because it's

```
data-label="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Excl. Tax'));?>">
```

and if You translate for options:

```
"Excl. Tax:","Excl. Vat:"
```

its always need to be exact phrase.

Another example from Module_Tax

```
"Excl. tax:","Excl. VAT:"
```

Remember to not add spaces between ","

Comment: Is my path to my file en_GB.csv and file name correct as I've changed the text to "Excl. Tax:", "Excl. Vat" and it hasn't changed the display on my store

Comment: Yes its correct if You use luma theme, if you use your custom app/design/frontend/YourVendor/YourTheme/i18n/en_GB.csv   , only one line is needed "Excl. Tax", "Excl. Vat"  , if you dont need any more translations

Comment: This is my path app/design/frontend/Magento/luma/i18n/en_GB.csv and I've tried both "Excl. Tax:, Excl. Vat:" & "Excl. Tax, Excl. Vat" (with and without the :'s). I run the commands php bin/magento setup:upgrade & php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f and the store still shows "Excl. Tax:" is there any other command I need to use?

Comment: Do You use inline Magento translation overwrites? Its translation from backend? You can try clean manually cache and later deploy rm -rf var/cache/* var/page_cache/* var/session/* var/view_preprocessed/pub/static/* pub/static/frontend/* generated/code/*

Comment: One more thing. Be sure that you dont have spaces between comma ","  I literally had this problem now with "My Wish List","My Favourites"   Your example is with space also.