# How to add new custom language Magento2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, language

Using magento from:

> -> Stores -> Configuration -> General -> Locale

Options, i can select the language from my country(Angola-Portuguese).

But using Magento command line for exemple: `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy pt_AO -f`

i get this error:

> pt_AO argument has invalid value, please run info:language:list for
>   list of available locales

And running this command :  `php bin/magento info:language:list`
i can't find the language of my country (Portuguese - Angola).

What i'm doing wrong with mi website ?

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because **`pt_AO`** is not included in the Magento list of allowed locales.

The best solution would be to use other allowed Portuguese locale.
You can check from [here](https://github.com/pepe1518/magento2/blob/master/vendor/magento/framework/Locale/Config.php)

Redeploy it, then using [collect phrases command](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-i18n.html#config-cli-subcommands-xlate-dict-dict) to collect and extract translatable words and phrases.
From there you can do the translation you want.
Check this: [Translation file magento 2 i18n](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269056/translation-file-magento-2-i18n/269072#269072)