# How to translate admin panel?

Tags: magento2, backend, translate, language-package

I need to translate magento 2 admin panel to Persian language.

Can anyone suggest to me the best ways to achieve this?

I suppose I need to download some language pack and then install it.

Or I just could export all the admin phrases and translate them manually and then install translated phrases.

If somebody could explain to me both ways I would be very thankful.

Comment: which version of Magento?

Comment: Magento 2.3.1 version

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this:

> Settings:
>   https://zemez.io/magento/support/how-to/magento-2-1-x-how-to-change-the-admin-panel-language/
>
> files needed:
>   https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-persian-language-pack.html

Answer (score 0):

You can actually change it directly from your **Admin Account Settings**
In the **Interface Locale**, choose **Persian** then Save.
After that, run static content deploy command:

```
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f fa_IR --area adminhtml
```

Then flush cache.
After that, you can [collect translatable phrases](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/269056/translation-file-magento-2-i18n?answertab=active#tab-top) for **`fa_IR`** which is the **Persian locale**.

```
php bin/magento i18n:collect-phrases --output "app/i18n/Magento/fa_IR.csv" --magento
```

Note: check the link in collect translatable phrases and do the same for manually translating words and deploy it afterwards

Comment: In the  Admin Account Settings->Interface Locale, I don't have the Persian language.
I don't have this directory as well:
app/i18n/Magento
And I wanted to clarify what exactly this command does:
--output "app/i18n/Magento/fa_IR.csv"
It collects csv data from this directory or creates it?
And where can I get this fa_IR.csv file?

Comment: It should be there just double check I think it is after the Egyptian locale. You have to create `app/i18n/Magento` directory then the command will generate the fa_IR.csv file inside of it.

Answer (score -1):

There is a Persian-Languagepack provided.

https://github.com/mageplaza/magento-2-persian-language-pack

Feel free to contribute if something is missing